# How to get full image data from thumbnail using Beatifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to code a program on Python that downloads a random image based on a search query. Here's my so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

query = 'pets' #This can be anything, this is just for demonstration 
adlt = 'on'
count = '10'

#I tried using Google but Bing is more cooperative
URL='https://bing.com/images/search?q=' + query + '&safeSearch=' + adlt + '&count=' + count

html_page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')

example = random.choice(images)

imageLink = example.attrs['src']

print(imageLink)
```

So, what this code does is it goes to Bing's image engine and gets all the  tags in there. Then it chooses a random one and prints it's URL on the terminal. But as you might know, what's shown on Bing's and Google's image engine isn't the actual image but a smaller version of it, you need to click it to access the actual image. So, from the data I get from this thumbnail how can I access the real image?

Here's the html code for a thumbnail in case you need it:

```
<img class="mimg" style="color: rgb(157, 102, 46);" height="180" width="323" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.1lJSjlsM4xmvJQTDwkOcbgHaEH?w=323&h=180&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7" alt="Image result for pets" data-thhnrepbd="1" data-bm="180">
```

And here's the code for the full image of that thumbnail:

```
<img src="http://www.insuranceportals.us/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Pets-Health-Insurance-Wise-Investment-Or-Waste-of-Money.jpeg" alt="See the source image" class=" nofocus" tabindex="0" aria-label="See the source image">
```

Comment: You answered it yourself.. you need to 'click it' to get to the image yourself.  I.e. find the url that the user is given when they click, and follow it. thumbnails are locally cached copies of the files stored on the Bing servers, there is no way to get to the original url from just the thumbnail.

Comment: @JeffUK So, is there any way to "click the image" using Beatifulsoup or any other API?

Comment: You could use Selenium for python

Comment: @Gealber From what I understand Selenium is basically a browser emulator. Every time you start Selenium the browser of your choice opens and that wouldn't be really convenient. I'd prefer something to do it with something that runs in the background.

Comment: Yes that's true, but you also can configure Selenium to run at the background as a headless browser. Something like this ```driver_options.add_argument("--headless")```. The problem is that you cannot simulate a `click` with bs4, because is just an html parser, a good one but just that. It cannot handle JavaScript for you

Answer (score 1):

The page is loaded dynamically, so `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
query = "pets"
adult = "on"
count = "10"

URL = (
    "https://bing.com/images/search?q="
    + query
    + "&safeSearch="
    + adult
    + "&count="
    + count
)
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
all_images = soup.find_all("img")
image = random.choice(all_images)
print(image)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
<img alt="Turtle" data-bm="78" data-priority="2" data-thhnrepbd="1" height="42" src2="https://th.bing.com/th?q=Pet+Turtle&amp;w=42&amp;h=42&amp;c=1&amp;p=0&amp;pid=InlineBlock&amp;mkt=en-US&amp;adlt=moderate&amp;t=1" width="42"/>
```

Comment: This might be a different way of doing what my code does. The problem still persists, the output you are getting is the link to the thumbnail of the image, not the actual image.